# Can i use cookies in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, cookies, phonegap-build

How can I use cookies to authenticate a user in PhoneGap for Android?

The server will send a cookie containing a session ID. As part of each future AJAX request to the server that cookie must get sent to authenticate the user. I don't have access to the server, so I can't change how it works.

So, I have to use cookies. I can't use local storage or anything like that, unless it behaves exactly like a browser would if a server were to send a "Set-Cookie" header.

How do I do this?

Comment: No, you can't use cookies in Cordova/Phonegap. Why won't you use local storage? http://justbuildsomething.com/cordova-and-express-session/

Answer (score 1):

Using local cookies with Cordova isn't possible, unless you can store them server-side. In your case, you can make use of local-storage, for easy values/flags/strings, or if you want a relational database, use WebSQL.

Local Storage:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

WebSQL: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

I would recommend WebSQL above others like IndexdDb because it is most wideley supported for mobile devices. See following link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage